# Is this website affiliated to Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, copyright, piracy

Is [WebCheatSheet](http://ask.webcheatsheet.com/) a Stack Exchange site?

Or is it copyright infringment?

Comment: view source: `<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100322154749-dcc77b1d701f)">` http://stackexchange.com is the hosted version of the SO engine. All fine and legal.

Comment: They are a stackexchange site, which is a hosted version of SO that others can rent to create their own SO type sites.  See http://stackexchange.com for more info.

Comment: And even if they were not a stackexchange site, it would probably still be far away from copyright infringement in most jurisdictions - it just would be a cheap 1:1 ripoff :)

Comment: Meta has been getting many questions lately similar to this one regarding StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100322154749-dcc77b1d701f)">
```

... it's a [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site.